# Google map polyline in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

We are making map based mobile application available on iOS and Android. We want to draw a route on map and for that we are using polyline in iOS. Here is the iOS code for it.

```
let polyline = infoArray[activeIndex].polyLine // Polyline code in string format
let path: GMSPath = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: polyline)!
let routePolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
routePolyline.strokeWidth = 3
routePolyline.map = mapView
```

But Android developer is unable how to draw it Android. How to do it for Android?

Comment: @Charuka I have gone through that post. We don't have list of latitudes and longitudes but just a code

Comment: same issue any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`PolyUtil.decode`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#decode-java.lang.String-) method from the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) to get a `List<LatLng>` from a `String` encoded polyline.

Comment: Is there any method to directly draw encoded poly line in android as in iOS

Comment: No, but the decoded `List` can be directly used by the `PolylineOptions.addAll` method